# podman cannot access the container using the windows LAN ipv4 address

Tags: podman, podman-in-podman, podman-networking

When the container is started, you can access it using 127.0.0.1:port, but you cannot access it using a native IPV4 address.

Moreover, `ipconfig /all` does not display the interface information of podman, but you can run `podman machine ssh` to enter the podman container and use `ifconfig` to see the interface information of podman. You can also access the container using the ip address of en0.

Windows firewall is off

The container uses the podman network configuration

```
 {
      "name": "podman_net",
      "id": "12123434556677788",
      "driver": "bridge",
      "network_interface": "podman1",
      "created": "2024-02-02T09:56:26.625364378+08:00",
      "subnets": [
           {
                "subnet": "10.89.0.0/24",
                "gateway": "10.89.0.1"
           }
      ],
      "ipv6_enabled": false,
      "internal": false,
      "dns_enabled": true,
      "ipam_options": {
           "driver": "host-local"
      }
}
```

Version detail info:

- Windows 10
- Podman 4.8.2

How do I access podman's container using local IPV4 and modify network config?

Comment: The "podman machine" is a virtual machine (running Linux) that runs your podman containers. So - you aren't running your containers directly on your Windows machine at all and they aren't going to have access to your network interface. What you can do is forward ports from your machine's interfaces to the containers in the VM. See the documentation for details.

Comment: yes，Configure the mapping and use it，thanks

Comment: "On Windows, each Podman machine is backed by a virtualized Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSLv2) distribution." [Docs](https://podman.io/docs/installation)

Answer (score 0):

windows 10 problem solution：Configure the mapping between the IP address and port of the WSL

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 listenport={host_port}connectaddress={your_podman_ip} connectport={wsl_port}
```